# Generate a tower of numbers in nested array

Tags: python

I want to produce a tower of numbers as

```
In [11]: print(res)                                                                                                           
[[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

My solution:

```
In [9]: for i in range(1, 6): 
   ...:     row = [1] * i 
   ...:     res.append(row)
```

How could combine the codes in one line.

Comment: You can use list comprehension. refer this blog for basic understanding - https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehension should work

```
print([[1]*i for i in range(1,6)])
#[[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

use list comprehension

```
In [3]: [[1]*i for i in range(1,6)]
Out[3]: [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
res=[[1]*i for i in range(1,6)]
```

Comment: add some explanation.